# Dynamic & static 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I  relative newbie to 301 redirects and I'm currently trying to set up redirects for an old site to a new site with dynamic urls and I'm not 100% sure I'm doing it right.

The new site is different from the old and on a new domain, both have a mix of static and dynamic urls which is making the redirects seem rather complicated.

```
I have the code below to redirect http://oldsite.co.uk/shop/products.php?cat=80 to http://newsite.co.uk/product

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^oldsite\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^cat=80$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/products\.php$ http://newsite/product? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Can anyone tell me if this is correct?

Also, I'm a little unsure on the correct format for redirecting static to dynamic eg.

```
redirecting http://oldsite.co.uk/shop/contact.php to http://newsite.co.uk/index.php?route=information/contact
```

One other thing I was unsure about is how to catch urls without creating individual redirects. I have nearly 2000 products on the site but rather than redirect them all I'd like to redirect the main category urls and have the products ust redirect to the main home page or category if that's possible.

Thanks